# How to schedule an email to be sent out on any given time?

Tags: send-email, scheduled

I would like to schedule an email going out on a given time to a given group or email? How do I go about it?

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. In particular, by using [edit], is this a recurring email you need to send or a one-time event?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go for 'Time-Dependent' Workflow.
Below link might help you if you are not aware of it.

[Time-Dependent Workflow Rule](https://www.shellblack.com/administration/time-dependent/)